# Making a conditional aggregate

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have tricky grouping problem for our business reasons, I have a table which has values like this

```
----------------------------
| NAME  |  TYPE   |  VALUE  |
----------------------------
|   N1  |   T1    |   V1    |
|   N1  |   T2    |   V2    |
|   N1  |  NULL   |   V3    |
|   N2  |   T2    |   V4    |
|   N2  |  NULL   |   V5    |
|   N3  |  NULL   |   V6    |
-----------------------------
```

I need to group it in a way that,

- The first level grouping will be by name.
- At the second level,

  - When the available types are T1,T2 and NULL, group T1 and NULL together and have T2 grouped seperately.
  - When the available types are T2 and NULL, group NULL with T2.
  - When NULL is the only available type, just have it as it is.

The expected O/P for the above table is,

```
----------------------------
|   N1  |   T1    | V1+V3   |
|   N1  |   T2    |   V2    |
|   N2  |   T2    | V4+V5   |
|   N3  |  NULL   |   V6    |
-----------------------------
```

How to achieve this in snowflake sql. Or any other server, so that I can find an equivalent in Snowflake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should work:

```
SELECT t1.NAME, COALESCE(TYPE, MIN_TYPE), SUM(VALUE)
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT NAME, MIN(TYPE) AS MIN_TYPE
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY NAME
) AS t2 ON t1.NAME = t2.NAME    
GROUP BY t1.NAME, COALESCE(TYPE, MIN_TYPE)
```

The query uses a derived table in order to extract the `MIN(TYPE)` value per `NAME`. Using `COALESCE` we can then convert `NULL` to either `T1` or `T2`.

**Edit:**

You can create a pivoted version of the expected result set using the following query:

```
SELECT NAME, 
       CASE 
          WHEN T1SUM IS NULL THEN 0
          ELSE COALESCE(T1SUM, 0) + COALESCE(NULLSUM,0)
       END AS T1SUM,
       CASE 
          WHEN T1SUM IS NULL AND T2SUM IS NOT NULL 
             THEN COALESCE(T2SUM, 0) + COALESCE(NULLSUM,0)
          ELSE COALESCE(T2SUM, 0)
       END AS T2SUM,
       CASE 
          WHEN T1SUM IS NULL AND T2SUM IS NULL THEN COALESCE(NULLSUM,0)
          ELSE 0
       END AS NULLSUM  
FROM (
   SELECT NAME, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'T1' THEN VALUE END) AS T1SUM,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'T2' THEN VALUE END) AS T2SUM,
          SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IS NULL THEN VALUE END) AS NULLSUM
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY NAME) AS t
```

Comment: Thats cool. Can it be achieved without self-join? 'mytable' itself is an abstraction of a big aggregate result.

Answer (score 0):

So in Giorgos's answer that totals are given in a pivoted, or single row be case form, not many rows per case, and this can be written simpler:

with this data:

```
WITH data_table(name, type, value) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (10, 1, 100 ),
    (10, 2, 200 ),
    (10, null, 400 ),
    (11, 2, 100 ),
    (11, null, 200 ),
    (12, null, 100 )
)
```

and this SQL

```
SELECT name
    ,SUM(IFF(type=1, value, null)) as t1_val
    ,SUM(IFF(type=2, value, null)) as t2_val
    ,SUM(IFF(type is null, value, null)) as tnull_val
    ,IFF(t1_val is not null, t1_val + zeroifnull(tnull_val), null) as c1_sum
    ,IFF(t1_val is not null, t2_val, t2_val + zeroifnull(tnull_val)) as c2_sum
    ,IFF(t1_val is null AND t2_val is null, tnull_val, null) as c3_sum
FROM data_table
GROUP BY 1;
```

we get:

| NAME | T1_VAL | T2_VAL | TNULL_VAL | C1_SUM | C2_SUM | C3_SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 100 | 200 | 400 | 500 | 200 | null |
| 11 | null | 100 | 200 | null | 300 | null |
| 12 | null | null | 100 | null | null | 100 |

which shows for the `10` row the null sum binds with 1 sum, for the `11` row the null sum binds with the 2 sum, and in the `12` row we get the null sum by itself.

We can unpivot these values if we wish, but joining to a mini table with 3 rows like so:

```
SELECT d.name,
    p.c2 as type,
    case p.c1
        WHEN 1 then d.c1_sum
        WHEN 2 then d.c2_sum
        ELSE d.c3_sum
    end as value
FROM (
    SELECT name
        ,SUM(IFF(type=1, value, null)) as t1_val
        ,SUM(IFF(type=2, value, null)) as t2_val
        ,SUM(IFF(type is null, value, null)) as tnull_val
        ,IFF(t1_val is not null, t1_val + zeroifnull(tnull_val), null) as c1_sum
        ,IFF(t1_val is not null, t2_val, t2_val + zeroifnull(tnull_val)) as c2_sum
        ,IFF(t1_val is null AND t2_val is null, tnull_val, null) as c3_sum
    FROM data_table
    GROUP BY 1
) AS d
JOIN (
    SELECT column1 as c1, column2 as c2 
    FROM VALUES (1,'T1'),(2,'T2'),(null,'null')
) AS p 
    ON ((d.c1_sum is not null AND p.c1 = 1) 
        OR (d.c2_sum is not null AND p.c1 = 2) 
        OR (d.c3_sum is not null AND p.c1 is null))
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

which gives the original requested output:

| NAME | TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | T1 | 500 |
| 10 | T2 | 200 |
| 11 | T2 | 300 |
| 12 | null | 100 |